# How to automatically find similarities in Java bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

Not sure if the title is the most descriptive way of putting it, but it's about as descriptive as I could think of.

Anyway, onto the question. I want to know how I can find similarities in bytecode. What I mean by this is rather difficult to properly explain (at least for me), so I will give an example instead.

I have aba.class, and nhf.class. These classes are obfuscated classes from a game I made. I offer a modified version of this game which simply has some small code changes in some places, but because the game is for sale it gets reobfuscated every time there is a new update. I want to be able to tell what class has changed to what in the reobfuscation by checking how similar the bytecode is for the classes. I know this is possible, but I have no idea how to check how to do this.

Is there a library, program or something that can parse bytecode and check how similar it is, or would I have to write this myself? If I would have to write it myself, I would appreciate someone to point me in the right direction (or link me to something that might help, etc).

Also, I'm looking at doing this with code, rather than manually, in case that wasn't apparent.

Comment: You could start diff-ing the `javap` outputs of both classes. Maybe ignoring the symbols table (or just comparing their sizes). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html

Comment: Well I guess size is a start, but ideally I wish to be able to identify classes, methods and fields (maybe not fields so much except for a few unique fields) even if the actual functionality (not just field/method/class names) has been changed a bit (obviously not if half the class has been rewritten). I think I'll look at the size thing though and hopefully implement it, thanks for the information!

Comment: You wrote the code right ? Would you not already know the answer ?

Comment: The example I gave was not what I wanted to do, it was an example. My actual use case is relatively complex and it doesn't need to be covered here.

Comment: @Marcelo Javap isn't designed to handle obfuscated classes. I'd recommend using a more powerful disassembler like Krakatau (which I wrote). You can find it at https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau, though I'd recommend waiting a day because I'm currently in the process of making major changes to improve attribute support.

Comment: @Antimony thanks for the link, I'll take a look at that now and see what I can do if there isn't anything specifically for finding bytecode similarities.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a simpler solution:

I don't know what obfuscator you use (maybe Proguard), but it probably generates a map that maps obfuscated classnames to non-obfuscated classnames. (If not, you can switch to Produard, which generates such map.)

So, you can translate obfuscated classnames to original classnames (and vice versa) provided that you have the map for the version.

So, you can make such map from these two maps by matching original classnames.